# Why are unset and empty variables numerically equal to zero with double brackets

Tags: bash, shell

The following code (tested with bash, zsh, and ksh, results may vary for other shells) returns `a is 0 (num)`.  The same happens for `a=''`.  Results for assigning `a=0` or `a=1` are predictable.  Quoting expressions does not change the result.  So, why do double brackets treat null and empty variables as being numerically equal to zero?

```
unset a
#a=''
#a=0
#a=1
if [[ $a == 1 ]] ; then 
   echo 'a is 1 (string)' 
fi
if [[ "$a" == 0 ]] ; then 
   echo 'a is 0 (string)' 
fi
if [[ $a -eq 1 ]] ; then 
   echo 'a is 1 (num)' 
fi
if [[ "$a" -eq 0 ]] ; then 
   echo 'a is 0 (num)' 
fi
```

I'm deliberately avoiding the broader issues of single and double brackets, since it's very well covered other places on this site and elsewhere.  Surprisingly, I've been unable to find anything that documents this particular behavior.

Further evidence:

```
unset a ; if [[ $a -gt -1 ]] ; then echo 'a > -1' ; fi
unset a ; if [[ $a -lt  1 ]] ; then echo 'a <  1' ; fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is explicitly documented, but  it's the `-eq` operator that forces a quasi-arithmetic context for its operands. Consider:

```
$ [[ "(3 + 5)" -eq 8 ]] && echo qed
qed
```

The behavior for variables is documented under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION:

> A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to
>          0 when referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

though it's not obvious that this should also apply to a string that results from a parameter expansion, and indeed the behavior is different in an arithmetic expression or arithmetic command itself:

```
$ unset a
$ (( a == 0 )) && echo zero
zero
$ (( $a == 0 )) && echo zero
bash: ((: == 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 0 ")
```

Given that you already have `$((...))` and `((...))` available for arithmetic, it's best to avoid `-eq` and the other arithmetic comparison operators inside `[[`; either use `[ "$a" -eq 0 ]` (which will raise an error if `a` is null or unset) or use `(( a == 0 )`.

Comment: Double checking, it's not clear whether `[[ ]]` uses shell arithmetic in [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) nor [gnu's Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b), and `[[ ]]` isn't mentioned in the shell arithmetic section, HOWEVER, [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) does note "When used with the [[ command, Arg1 and Arg2 are evaluated as arithmetic expressions (see Shell Arithmetic)"

Answer (score 2):

It's well documented in the manual: [6.5 Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic)

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax. A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

and

> A null value evaluates to 0.

Your tests are running into the 2nd case.

I can't tell you the design rationale behind it. It is handy in practice though:

```sh
unset a
(( a++ ))
echo $a    # => 1
```

Also, other languages do the same thing:

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN {if (unset_variable == 0) print "zero"}'
zero

$ perl -E 'if ($unset_variable == 0) {say "zero"}'
zero
```

Comment: There's a small difference here, though: a shell variable isn't being used; the result of a parameter expansion is.

Comment: The OP's code demonstrates that null value is treated as zero. My example shows that an unset variable is treated as zero. The bash manual covers both cases.

Comment: Ah, I did misinterpret that.

Answer (score 0):

> So, why do double brackets treat null and empty variables as being numerically equal to zero?

From [bash shell manual 6.5 Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

> A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax

The quotes inside bash extension `[[` compound command do not matter, because word splitting expansion is not performed inside `[[`.